# import already created sqlite database (xamarin)

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin.android, android-sqlite, monodevelop

I'm using Xamarin and want to know how to import an sqlite database I've already created. So far ive added it to the assets folder but dont know where to start next.

Answer (score 1):

```
string localPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), YourAppName);

//Directory with your DB3 file
var dirx = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString();

// DB File 
var dbfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(dirx , "/YourAppName/YourSQLiteDB.db3");



            if (File.Exists(dbfile))
            {

                File.Copy(dbfile, localPath, true);
                Toast.MakeText(this, "SQLiteDB copied successfully!", ToastLength.Long).Show();


            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "copy from " + diry +         System.Environment.NewLine + "to " + localPath + " failed or source file is missing!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
}
```